# How can I integrate lambdas em AWS environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

I have a doubt about how to integrate lambdas in AWS environment.
For this project, we decided to use an approach that works without services.

The concept is simple, but I don't know what is the best way to implement it.

I wish isolated executions - how I suppose that lambda has to be - so that a lambda doesn't know each other.

In principle, I intend to create 3 lambdas. The first one receive the payload from API Gateway.

The question is: What is the best way to pass a payload from de first lambda to the second and so on?

I'm going to use SQS, but SQS isn't a valid event source to Lambdas (please check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html).

So, I suppose I should use some service like SNS or Kinesis.

I really want avoid that my lambdas do polling in a queue manually. I think that lambda could lose its essence. I prefer to work with push events.

I accept all suggestions since I may have misunderstood some concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Kinesis seems like the best fit. A very similar question was asked here: [How to process SQS queue with lambda function (not via scheduled events)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678691/how-to-process-sqs-queue-with-lambda-function-not-via-scheduled-events/34697530)

Comment: From a cost perspective, as well. If you're pushing any kind of volume, Kinesis is much cheaper than SQS.

Comment: Good, thank you. I've read this question too. But can I emulate a Chain of Responsibility with that combination (lambda + kinesis)? I mean I have a payload processed by a lambda and forwarded to another lambda, but they don't know each other. Kinesis control this flow like streams? Or am I going the wrong way?

Thank you again.